# Which disk IO operations are typically executed when working with flat preallocated VMDK

Tags: hard-drive, performance, virtual-machine

I usually pre-allocate whole disk space when creating my VMs and usually as flat single files. Since I'd like to move my VMDK to a different drive than my primary I would like to put it on one that has best performance of particular read/write disk IO type.

### Question

What is typical disk operation when working with virtual preallocated flat files? Is it sequential, random 512, 4k? Anything else I should know about?

The thing is I've bought a very fast SDHC (SanDisk UHS-I ExtremePro with advertised 95MB/s read speed) card and I'd like to put my VM on it.

When I run CrystalDiskMark it reports these results:

```
         MB/s MB/s
------------------
Seq:     7.7  7.4
512:     7.7  3.8
4k:      3.9  1.3
4k QD32: 3.9  1.3
```

Especially the 4k speeds are higher than my USB2 attached 7200 platter disk.

Comment: If they are higher then your 7200 platter disks whats the problem?

Comment: @Ramhound the 4k are higher but others aren't. Hence my question...

Comment: The table isn't even clear.  You told us nothing about which specific products you have.  Clarify the table and provide the product information.

Comment: @Ramhound: Isn't clear? it displays disk read/write performance in MB/s for each individual type of IO work operations. If you'd run CrystalDiskMark you'd see what these mean. *Seq* means sequential reads/writes of a long file, then we have 512k sizes and 4k... WHat else should be cleared about table data? These info is related to aforementioned SDHC card...

Comment: If it was clear I wouldn't have asked. I understand what the table say just not sure which column is what.